# Is it possible to monetize the hosting of a GPL-v3 licensed app?

Tags: gpl-3

If I understood correctly, every derivative of a GPL-v3 licensed software is imbued with the GPL-v3 license.

Does this mean that I have to disclose the code I used for the infrastructure that runs the GPL app? What about the web UI, the bash scripts etc. etc.? What if I don't use code per se to interact with the GPL-v3 licensed software (rest API, something else)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your title says "monetize" but your question makes it clear you ask more precisely about copyleft obligations and source disclosure (which aren't concerns that are strictly aligned with monetization). If you really ask about monetization, the GPL specifies no limits on how much you may charge for a transferring copy, or any other permitted action (e.g., making modifications, or hosting a copy online for a client or users).

The GPL requires you to offer the source code to any recipients to whom you give (including as part of a sale, or gratis) a copy of a GPL-licensed binary file. Most network services do not involve giving a copy of a binary file to users of the service, so the source-sharing obligations of the GPL does not apply merely because a computer sending some network traffic to a user has privately executed GPL-licensed code.

If there is GPL-licensed code sent to the user as part of, e.g., a web UI, then that component would carry GPL source-sharing requirements, which might extend to the other client-side code components, depending on how your jurisdiction's copyright laws view how they interact with one another and do/don't create a new derivative client-side work. Client-side GPL code would very likely not impose source-sharing requirements on any server-side code that is never sent to the user.

The Affero GPL (AGPL) is a different, more strict license that *does* impose source-sharing requirements in this network case, but you've asked about the GPL, not the AGPL.